# A bug in some links

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/13104/1712) had a long link, which was not showing correctly after saving, it was showing ok in preview while editing.. but after posting it doesn't. Check the history to see how does it look like. I had to shorten the link using [bitly](http://bit.ly) to make it show correctly.

**Example: Click edit to see that the link below is fine in preview while edit but not after saving:**

[This is an example](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=fr&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.fr&sl=ko&tl=en&u=http://culture.jeju.go.kr/contents/?mid=020501&usg=ALkJrhiH12b6t8aA2nZkwpSK-BwafVi_ZA).

Comment: That's really bizarre!